# How to code C# to allow one tap to cause the character to jump for Android device in 3d game

Tags: unity, android

Is there a native unity 5 to implement one tap to have the character to jump.?
My game is 3d and I want to tap anywhere once or in the character.

I found a MobileTiltController as part of the CrossPlataformInput but I don't see a jump option. 
My Character is a rolling ball.
Can anybody show me the code to do this.?
I've used different codes found in internet but they don't work. 
for example this [link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/305878/how-to-add-jump-control-from-touch-on-screen-andro.html) says to use the code below, but AddForce is not found.

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up*popForce,ForceMode.Force);
```

I don't know how to build the whole C# file. (update, start...)

Other codes are counting the number of taps but I don't know what to do after that.

Comment: It sounds like you would need someone to write the *entire* script, if you are still unfamiliar with even the basics, such as the Update function. The Unity website offers great scripting tutorials. Just start at the first tutorial and work your way on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to complete the whole file based on the code above. It is basic, but this works fine for now.
Credit to [Raja Biswas](https://youtu.be/TEROHR1XTaY?list=PLytjVIyAOStrTBXBuuMR0HjXGIk4DtJrv)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class adr_balance : MonoBehaviour {

    GameObject player;
    Rigidbody rigidbody;
    float popForce=100f;

    void Start(){
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
            rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up*popForce,ForceMode.Force);

    }

}
```